# Conditionally Render Component In Visualforce Page

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I would like to conditionally render a `component` in a `VisualForce` page based on a custom field.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
<apex:page standardController="myObject__c">
    <c:myComponent myProperty="{! Id }" render="{! myBoolean__c }" />
</apex:page>
```

`Component`s don't have a `render` property though.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The property you're looking for is called [`rendered`](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/pages_compref_component.htm), not `render`. And it's available on most (if not all) tags.